# How to prevent multiple login to the same account in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0

I'm using [ASP.NET Core 6 Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio) for login system. I want to prevent multiple login to the same account.
My `Identity` settings are:

//For custom Identity

```
string connection = configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
builder.Services.AddIdentity<AppUser, AppRole>(options =>
{
    options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = false;
    options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
    options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
    options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 0;
    options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
    options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
    options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
    options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 10;
    options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);
    options.Tokens.PasswordResetTokenProvider = TokenOptions.DefaultProvider;
}).AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityAppContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

I searched some similar questions but none of them could help me to implement this feature in ASP.NET Core 6.
Please guide me.

Comment: Are you saying that when someone logs in, you want to make sure they don't have another active login session at the time, and allow or reject the login based on that?

Comment: When someone logged in, no body can log in to that account until he closes the browser or logs out manually.

Comment: What is the Use Case for denying access while logged in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the Use Case for denying access while logged in?

"When someone logged in, no body can log in to that account until he closes the browser or logs out manually"

That would require logic like:
On Login, throw error if tokenHasBeenIssued, by querying the server db.
On Login, if no server token for user, createToken.
On Logout, a clean db, removeUserToken

but, when someone closes their browser there is no message sent to the server, so you'd never clear the token, so you'd get one login granted and then they would be logged out forever.

Maybe this scenario is fixable with a hack of a 'Timed cron job to clear all old tokens'?

I would suggest implement two factor authentication or even delegate your auth needs to third party provider, eg Auth0 or Azure AD, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to stay signed in, you need to implement a token(for example, JWT Token) and use User ID or username directly without logging in again.